In Late Latin (the time of Jerome), was "quia" more often used in the sense "because" or in the sense "that" (as a substitution for AcI and NcI)?
On another forum, we were discussing whether "quia" was, in Late Latin (Jerome...), more commonly used to mean "because" or to mean "that" (instead of Accusative with Infinitive and Nominative with Infinitive). Has anybody done a study on that? I'd expect that the number of "that"-es is a lot more common, since, for example, in Matthew 5, Jerome uses "quia" to mean "that" in three consecutive sentences:

Dico enim vobis, quia nisi abundaverit justitia vestra plus quam scribarum et pharisæorum, non intrabitis in regnum cælorum.
Audistis quia dictum est antiquis : Non occides : qui autem occiderit, reus erit judicio. Ego autem dico vobis : quia omnis qui irascitur fratri suo, reus erit judicio.


To clarify one thing, the Vulgate may not necessarily be typical of Late Antique Latin. Jerome's translational method involved rendering each Greek word with a single, consistent Latin word where possible. So, the Greek article hoti (almost?) always becomes quia. Thus, the frequency of quia introducing substantive clauses in the Vulgate is partly an artifact of the source text. ACI was still the preferred method up to ~400 CE. Vide: https://people.ischool.berkeley.edu/~dbamman/pubs/pdf/pbml2008.pdf
